# Is this the correct way to get the $25^{th}$, $50^{th}$, and $75^{th}$ percentile?

Tags: statistics

From the frequency distribution in the image below,

$P_{25} = 0.25(53) = 13.25$

$13.25$ falls between index $1$ and $2$, so then $\dfrac{1+2}{2} = 1.5$, round up, $2$.

$P_{25} = 35.8\%$

---

$P_{50} = 0.50(53) = 26.5$

$26.5$ falls between index $2$ and $3$, so then $\dfrac{2+3}{2} = 2.5$, round up, $3$.

$P_{50} = 52.8\%$

---

$P_{75} = 0.75(53) = 39.75$

$39.75$ falls between index $4$ and $5$, so then $\dfrac{4+5}{2} = 4.5$, round up, $5$.

$P75 = 75.5\%$

Here is the frequency distribution:
[image: The Frequency distribution]

Please help

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to understand your calculations. You shoud focus on the column of Cumulative Pct., last one, and see on which ranges fall the 25%, 50% and 75%, namely:

```
25% -> (<85-90)
50% -> (80.5-85)
75% -> (70.5-75)
```

Edit: reviewing it, I think you are looking at the column of the isolated percentage of each range. Notice that a percentile is the value below which a given percentage of observations in a group of observations fall. So in your case a 75% of the observations are located in the range 70.5-75 or before

Comment: Would the 25th percentile then be 70.68 ?

Comment: As posted in the answer the 25% percentile is the range (<85-90), not a number

Comment: I thought the idea of percentiles is it would give you a point in the range of percentiles listed. So then the one which just exceeds 25% would be the 25 percentile and the 50th percentile the one that just exceeds 50% and so on.

Comment: The data given don't give you enough information to make such a fine grained distinction.  You have been told that 35.8% of the scores are above 85, and 15.1% of the scores are above 90.  This means that the 25th percentile must be between 85 and 90.  It is reasonable to write that the 25th percentile is in this range, or that it is $87.5\pm 2.5$, or that `<85-90` is the 25th percentile.  Personally, I kind of like $87.5\pm 2.5$, as this succinctly gives an idea about how much precision you have.